# How to get Environment name from inside SSIS dtsx

Tags: ssis, environment-variables

When something goes wrong in my dtsx I want to send an email.
In the email, among other info, I need to know which Environment the parameters and connection info were taken from.
I can't find any suitable system::variable to do this.

How can I do?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable in the package configuration, and have a different value for it in each environment's .config file.